# ReactJS not able to reference state created

Tags: javascript, reactjs

http://jsfiddle.net/adamchenwei/3rt0930z/11/

I just trying to create an example to learn how state works in a list.

What I intent to do is to allow a particular value that got repeated in a list, to change, in ALL items in the list, by using state. For example, in this case, I want to change all the name to 'lalala' when I run `changeName` of onClick.

However I have this warning:

[image]

How can I resolve it to achieve the purpose above?

Actual Code

```
var items = [
    { name: 'Believe In Allah', link: 'https://www.quran.com' },
    { name: 'Prayer', link: 'https://www.quran.com' },
    { name: 'Zakat', link: 'https://www.quran.com' },
    { name: 'Fasting', link: 'https://www.quran.com' },
  { name: 'Hajj', link: 'https://www.quran.com' },
];

var ItemModule = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { newName: this.props.name }
    },
    changeName() {
    this.setState({ newName: 'lalala' });
  },
    render() {
    //<!-- <a className='button' href={this.props.link}>{this.props.name}</a> -->
    return (
        <li onClick={this.changeName()}>
        
        {this.state.newName}
      </li>
    );
  }
});

var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { items: [] }
    },
    render: function() {

        var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <div>
            <li key={item.name}>
            {item.name}
          </li>

          <ItemModule
            name={item.name} />
        </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className='pure-menu'>
                <h3>Islam Pillars</h3>
                <ul>
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />,                 
    document.getElementById('react-content'));
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `onClick={this.changeName}`

Comment: Editor's note: this question was edited to include the fixes given in the answers, effectively turning it into a different question. To maintain parity with the existing answers I have rolled it back to the matching edit (rev 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the parenthesis from

`onClick={this.changeName()}`,

so

`onClick={this.changeName}`

you want to call the function onClick, but you are calling it on render that way

Comment: you need to pass a unique number to key, common practice is to pass the index of the current iteration

Comment: I udpated my fiddle. same thing after I added index. thought?

Comment: key must go on the wrapper container, ItemModule is inside a div, add the key to the div instead

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to do `onClick={this.changeName}`

In the way you have it you are calling the `changeName` function on render instead of on click.